# How to determine if current location falls inside a GMaps polygon?

Tags: php, geolocation, coordinates, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems

We're trying to be able to draw a polygon in either Google Maps or Google Earth and to get a range of coordinates, give it an ID, after that be able to identify if a current location GPS latitude and longitude coordinates fall in which of those polygons ID to suggest where you are.

This is for a cool invention that it's going to be used by thousands of users.

I've found some guidance in following questions but not the complete picture:

- [Finding a set of coordinates within a certain range from latitude longitide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552334/finding-a-set-of-coordinates-within-a-certain-range-from-latitude-longitide)
- [Get countries within range of LAT/LONG coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669438/get-countries-within-range-of-lat-long-coordinates)
- [How do I check if a longitude/latitude point is within a range of coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510326/how-do-i-check-if-a-longitude-latitude-point-is-within-a-range-of-coordinates)

Comment: This is rather broad at the moment. Have you rendered Google Maps on your browser screen using JavaScript? That's the first thing. Then, have you drawn any polygons? Try drawing a demo one at your home location, just for test purposes, made up of just a few points. Then, third, see if the API offers a way to check if a polygon contains a point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map: is a lat/lng within a polygon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318812/google-map-is-a-lat-lng-within-a-polygon)